# Accuracy assessment in GEE with an external data source

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, confusion-matrix, accuracy-assessment

I'm new on GEE and I'm trying to perform an accuracy assessment of a supervised classification from S1 of a flood area, by the use of a confusion matrix.

Once the model is created, in order to evaluate it, I imported a shapefile with data relating the reality on the ground regarding the flood, and from this shapefile I selected a sample of polygons of flooded and non-flooded areas, created a new feature collection and then through the confusion matrix I wanted to compare this new dateset with the model to obtain an evaluation of the classification.

This is the code  I used:

```
//create a feature collection of samples (samples are polygons set as geometry).
var newFc = ee.FeatureCollection( [ee.Feature(water_permanent, {'landCover':1} ),
                                        ee.Feature(water_flooded, {'landCover':2} ),
                                        ee.Feature(urban, {'landCover':3} ),
                                        ee.Feature(agricultural_field,{'landCover’:4})] );
                                        
//Overlay the points on the imagery to get training 
//(UnionMed is the starting image from where I took the samples).

var training = unionMed.sampleRegions({
  collection: newFc,
  scale:10,
  properties:['landCover'],
  tileScale:16
});

//Define the classifier and train it.

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train(training, "landCover");

//Classify the image.

var classified = unionMed.classify(classifier);

//Accuracy Asssesment.

//define a new FC from the reference shapefile.

var newFc_test = ee.FeatureCollection( [ee.Feature(No_WF_test, {'landCover_test':1} ),
                                        ee.Feature(WF_test, {'landCover_test’:2})]);
                                        
var validated = classified.sampleRegions({
  collection: newFc_test,
  properties: ['landCover_test'],
  scale:10,
  tileScale:16
});

//Classify the validation data.

var validation=validatio.classify(classifier);

//Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.

var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('landCover','landCover_test')
print('Confusion matrix:', testAccuracy)
print('Accuracy:', testAccuracy.accuracy())
```

The problem is that I get this error:

ConfusionMatrix (Error)
Collection.errorMatrix: Property 'VV' of feature '0_0' is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of typos in your code (validation, valdatio, validated), but it looks like the problem is you're attempting to classify your validation data, but it has no covariates.  You're already sampling the classified image, so there's no reason to classify it.  Just remove that line.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried as you suggested and the error resolved, however now I am getting an empty confusion matrix of 1x1. This is the last part of the code updated:                                                                                                                      
`var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('landCover','landCover_test');`